# Change notifyIcon1 from resources

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, notifyicon

this code recall a icon from external file:

```
notifyIcon1.Icon = new Icon("notifier.ico");
```

if possible change the icon from resources file?

```
notifyIcon1.Icon = new Icon(Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.icon2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Properties.Resources.icon2` is already an `Icon`.